# VB.Net Global DataSets inside a public function

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, dataset, global

I am having some problem with a function that I hope you can help.

My Application is a simple one, it uses an Access database to load employee information and creates letters and financial breakdown sheet from word templates that users can then print and save back to the database.

I started by creating a dataset containing several datatables for each form subroutine but it resulted in literally hundreds of lines of repeated code. But it worked.

What I want to do, is have one dataset containing all the information needed about an employee and be able to reference it over several forms at the same time. So i created a public module that looks like this:

```
Public Module Datasets
Public update As String
Dim pCn As OleDb.OleDbConnection

Public Function CSofwareDataSet() As DataSet
    'open new connection to database
    pCn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\CGI Project\CorrespondenceSoftware\Database1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;")
    Try
        Call pCn.Open() 'opens the connection
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could not open a database connection! 1")
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    CSofwareDataSet = New DataSet
Dim daOPG As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Overpayment WHERE PayNumber='" & Main.tbPayNumber.Text & "' AND Gross=1", pCn) 'get all data from Overpayment Details table
Dim daOPN As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Overpayment WHERE PayNumber='" & Main.tbPayNumber.Text & "' AND Net=1", pCn) 'get all data from Overpayment Details table
Dim daOPR As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM OvpReasons", pCn) 'get overpayment reasons
Dim daREC As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TaxYear", pCn) 'get recovery date options
Dim daEMP As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails WHERE PayNumber='" & Main.tbPayNumber.Text & "' AND Active=1 ", pCn) 'get all data from Employee Details table
Dim daCON As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Consultant", pCn) 'get all data from Consultant Details table
Dim daSET As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Settings", pCn) 'get all data from Consultant Details table
'Find the primary key (if missing)
    daOPG.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    daOPN.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    daOPR.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    daREC.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    daEMP.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    daCON.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    daSET.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
'setup prefixes
Dim cbOPG As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daOPG)
    cbOPG.QuotePrefix = "["
    cbOPG.QuoteSuffix = "]"
Dim cbOPN As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daOPN)
    cbOPG.QuotePrefix = "["
    cbOPG.QuoteSuffix = "]"
Dim cbOPR As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daOPR)
    cbOPG.QuotePrefix = "["
    cbOPG.QuoteSuffix = "]"
Dim cbREC As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daREC)
    cbOPG.QuotePrefix = "["
    cbOPG.QuoteSuffix = "]"
Dim cbEMP As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daEMP)
    cbEMP.QuotePrefix = "["
    cbEMP.QuoteSuffix = "]"
Dim cbCON As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daCON)
    cbEMP.QuotePrefix = "["
    cbEMP.QuoteSuffix = "]"
Dim cbSET As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daSET)
    cbEMP.QuotePrefix = "["
    cbEMP.QuoteSuffix = "]"



    If CSofwareDataSet.HasChanges Then
        Try
            daEMP.Update(CSofwareDataSet, "EmployeeDetails")
            daOPG.Update(CSofwareDataSet, "OverPaymentGross")
            daOPN.Update(CSofwareDataSet, "OverPaymentNet")
            daSET.Update(CSofwareDataSet, "Settings")

            MessageBox.Show("Success! Records updated.")
            update = "0"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Oops - something went wrong and it didn't update")
            update = "0"
        End Try
    ElseIf CSofwareDataSet.Tables.Count = 0 Then
        daOPG.Fill(CSofwareDataSet, "OverPaymentGross")
        daOPN.Fill(CSofwareDataSet, "OverPaymentNet")
        daOPR.Fill(CSofwareDataSet, "OverPaymentReasons")
        daREC.Fill(CSofwareDataSet, "RecoveryDates")
        daEMP.Fill(CSofwareDataSet, "EmployeeDetails")
        daCON.Fill(CSofwareDataSet, "ConsultantDetails")
        daSET.Fill(CSofwareDataSet, "Settings")

    End If


    'If update = "1" Then
    ' Try
    ' daEMP.Update(CSofwareDataSet, "EmployeeDetails")
    ' daOPG.Update(CSofwareDataSet, "OverPaymentGross")
    ' daOPN.Update(CSofwareDataSet, "OverPaymentNet")
    ' daSET.Update(CSofwareDataSet, "Settings")
    '
    '        MessageBox.Show("Success! Records updated.")
    '        update = "0"
    '        Catch ex As Exception
    ' MessageBox.Show("Oops - something went wrong and it didn't update")
    ' update = "0"
    ' End Try
    ' End If

    pCn.Close()

End Function
End Module
```

On each form, it gets referenced like this (as an example):

```
Imports WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Imports CorrespondenceSoftware.Datasets

Public Class GrossInput

Dim loading = "1"
Dim NewEmployee = "0" 'sets the default new employee flag to 0
Private pCn As OleDb.OleDbConnection

Private Sub GrossInput_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Try

        Try
            If CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows.Count - 1
                    cbTitle.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(2)
                    tbFName.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(3)
                    tbLName.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(4)
                    tbAddress1.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(5)
                    tbAddress2.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(6)
                    tbAddress3.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(7)
                    tbAddress4.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(8)
                    tbPostcode.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(9)
                    tbWorkLocation.Text = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(i)(10)
                    tbWorkLocation.Enabled = False
                    tbPostcode.Enabled = False
                    tbAddress4.Enabled = False
                    tbAddress3.Enabled = False
                    tbAddress2.Enabled = False
                    tbAddress1.Enabled = False
                    tbLName.Enabled = False
                    tbFName.Enabled = False
                    cbTitle.Enabled = False
                    chkMSC.Enabled = False
                    chkOfficer.Enabled = False
                    chkStaff.Enabled = False
                    bnSaveEmp.Enabled = False
                    bnEditEmp.Enabled = True

                Next
            End If
            If CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(0)(11) = "1" Then
                chkOfficer.Checked = True
            Else
                chkOfficer.Checked = False

            End If
            If CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(0)(12) = "1" Then
                chkStaff.Checked = True
            Else
                chkStaff.Checked = False

            End If
            If CSofwareDataSet.Tables("EmployeeDetails").Rows(0)(13) = "1" Then
                chkMSC.Checked = True
            Else
                chkMSC.Checked = False

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            MessageBox.Show("Employee not found. Ensure pay number is correct and create a new record")
            NewEmployee = "1" ' tells the program to create a new record if saved
            cbReference.Enabled = False
            cbReference.Text = ""
            bnEditEmp.Enabled = False
        End Try

        'display the overpayment references to the user
        If CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentGross").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentGross").Rows.Count - 1
                cbReference.Items.Add(CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentGross").Rows(i)(2))
            Next
        End If
        'display the available consultants to the user
        If CSofwareDataSet.Tables("ConsultantDetails").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To CSofwareDataSet.Tables("ConsultantDetails").Rows.Count - 1
                cbConsultant.Items.Add(CSofwareDataSet.Tables("ConsultantDetails").Rows(i)(1) & " " & CSofwareDataSet.Tables("ConsultantDetails").Rows(i)(2))
            Next
        End If
        'display the available Overpayment reasons to the user
        If CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentReasons").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentReasons").Rows.Count - 1
                cbReason.Items.Add(CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentReasons").Rows(i)(1))
            Next
        End If
        'Load other recovery date options 
        If CSofwareDataSet.Tables("RecoveryDates").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To CSofwareDataSet.Tables("RecoveryDates").Rows.Count - 1
                cbStartRecovery.Items.Add(CSofwareDataSet.Tables("RecoveryDates").Rows(i)(1))
            Next
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString) 'Show any errors to the user
    End Try
    loading = "0"
End Sub
```

Now! the problem that I'm having is that, this does work and run without any errors BUT every time the CSSoftwareDataSet function runs it populates the tables correctly and returns the expected results but it then deletes the datatable data so every time the function is referenced from a winform it needs to haul all the data from the access database from scratch, severely impacting on the performance of the program. The tables wont update properly because its not storing the datatable information and as soon as its inserted its forgotten but again, produces no errors. An example of my update script looks like this:

```
 Else 'create a new record
        'create a new reference
        Dim REFRowCount = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentGross").Rows.Count + 1 'count the number of rows in table and add 1
        Dim NewREF = "OVPG" & Main.tbPayNumber.Text & "-" & REFRowCount
        'Find todays date and reply dates

        Dim TodayDatedate = Format(Now.Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
        Dim ReplyDatedate = Format(Now.Date.AddDays(21), "dd/MM/yyyy")

        'Create a new row
        Dim OPNew As DataRow = CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentGross").NewRow() 'create a variable to contain the new row
        OPNew.Item(1) = Main.tbPayNumber.Text
        OPNew.Item(2) = NewREF
        OPNew.Item(3) = tbOverpaymentAmount.Text.ToString
        OPNew.Item(4) = tbMonRec.Text
        OPNew.Item(5) = tbTaxP.Text
        OPNew.Item(6) = TodayDatedate
        OPNew.Item(7) = ReplyDatedate
        OPNew.Item(8) = tbMoRep.Text
        OPNew.Item(9) = cbStartRecovery.Text
        OPNew.Item(10) = "1" 'Set as gross
        OPNew.Item(11) = "0" 'do not set as net
        OPNew.Item(12) = cbReason.Text
        OPNew.Item(13) = tbAI.Text
        OPNew.Item(14) = dtpStart.Value.Date
        OPNew.Item(15) = dtpFinish.Value.Date
        OPNew.Item(16) = cbConsultant.Text
        OPNew.Item(17) = tbPosition.Text

        Call CSofwareDataSet.Tables("OverPaymentGross").Rows.Add(OPNew) 'fill the new row and insert the data
```

There must be a solution to this. To create a dataset that holds its data in session while you open other winforms until it is reset. I'm out of ideas because i really don't want to go back to repeating all this code for practically every subroutine in my program.

I hope I've explained it OK .. Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks, 
Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the `DataSet` globally, populate it in a function (sub), which is called just at the start, and retrieve the information by accessing the variable rather than by calling the function over and over. Your code uses a somehow ambiguous approach (same name for function and for variable) which, together with the VB rules (functions might not include a `Return` statement but a variable with the function's name) does not play to your favor.

Sample code converting the `DataSet` into a public variable and renaming the function (and converting it into a sub: what is the point of a function now?):

```
Public CSofwareDataSet As DataSet
Public Sub populateDS()
    'open new connection to database
    pCn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\CGI Project\CorrespondenceSoftware\Database1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;")
    Try
        Call pCn.Open() 'opens the connection
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Could not open a database connection! 1")
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    CSofwareDataSet = New DataSet

    'Remaining code

End Sub
```

Call this sub just once (right at the start of your application; or every time new data has to be retrieved from the DB) and continue using `CSofwareDataSet` as so far (although as a variable, by removing the `Call` bits; which, on the other hand, are not required in VB.NET at all).

Comment: Thats fantastic! Thank you .. that has solved the problem in its entirety. The dataset holding the information correctly throughout the entire program. How should i send these changes back to the database??

Comment: Don't worry! I figured it out, I created a seperate datatable, merged it and then used the new data adapters to send it back to the database via the usual update command. Thank you!!!

Comment: @ShaneMarsh You are welcome. I am happy to see that you figure out this last issue by your own.